# How to import htmlreg table to RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr

I created a table in R:

```
t1 <- lm(formula = `Variable1` ~ `Variable2`, data = my_table)

#- results = "asis"
table1 <- htmlreg(
 list(t1),
  include.ci = FALSE,
  star.symbol = "\\*",
  caption = "New Table",
  doctype = FALSE)
```

Then I saved the table:

```
saveRDS(
  table1, 
  here("variables/table1.rds")
)
```

Now, if I create a code chunk in RMD and try to reproduce the table there, it's not working:

```
{r echo=FALSE}


library(here)
table1 <- readRDS(
  here("variables/table1.rds")
)

table1
```

table1 just does not show up in the RMD when I knit it. How can I showcase the table in the knitted html from the RMD file?

Comment: Did the data file get saved? Did anything show up in the knitted result? Did you also want `results = 'asis'` in the second code chunk?

Comment: results = 'asis' worked!